# Datatable jquery server-side stuck on processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

i have some problem with datatable. Some of my datatable are stuck on "processing"
[image]

while some of them are doing okay. 
Here is the datatable code that are stuck on "processing"

```
$(function () {

        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            buttons: ['excel','pdf'],
            ajax: "https:myurl",
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                {data: 'nama', name: 'nama'},
                {data: 'contact_person', name: 'contact_person'},
                {data: 'telepon', name: 'telepon'},
                {data: 'alamat', name: 'alamat'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
            language: { 
                search: '', searchPlaceholder: "Search..." ,
                lengthMenu: '<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">'+
                            '<option value="10">Show 10 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="20">Show 20 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="30">Show 30 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="40">Show 40 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="50">Show 50 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="100">Show 100 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="500">Show 500 rows</option>'+
                            '<option value="-1">Show All</option>'+
                            '</select>'
            },
            dom: "<'row' <'col-sm-12 col-md-8'l> <'col-sm-12 col-md-4'f B<'toolbar'>>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
            "buttons": [
                'excel'
            ],
        });

        $(".toolbar").html('<a href="https:myurl" class="dt-button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');

    });
```

And here is the code that are doing okay

```
       $(function () {

        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "https:myUrl",
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'code_test', name: 'code_test'},
                {data: 'start_time', name: 'start_time'},
                {data: 'end_time', name: 'end_time'},
                {data: 'slug', name: 'slug'},
                {data: 'total', name: 'total'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]
        });
    });
```

I'm wondering why is that? Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you create a Code snippet or jsfiddle out of your code, so we can see how it is "stuck"?

Comment: I got the same issue, when I have 10k records. Yajra datatable may have slow.

Comment: @anton i don't think i can, because i need to login to my website to get the actual data. But in my local server my datatable was doing alright. This problem occured when i host my web to my vps

Comment: @DilipHirapara i think my records is still around hundreds.  in my local server my datatable was doing alright. This problem occured when i host my web to my vps